# How to encrypt the base64 image value in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, encoding

Here i am using file upload,user uploads large image means i want to re size and also don't want  to move any temporary folder in this image so i can used **base64_encode()**,still now i am getting correct answer after that i want do one thing ,i want encrypt the value for base64_encode image value,how can do this one?

---

Here i got base64 encoded image value

```
$encodeimage =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

```
<?php
define ("MAX_SIZE","1000");
 $errors=0;
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
      if ($image) 
      {
      $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
      $extension = getExtension($filename);
      $extension = strtolower($extension);
     if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
      {
        $error_msg = ' Unknown Image extension ';
        $errors=1;
      }
     else{
         $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
        {
         $error_msg = "You have exceeded the size limit";
         $errors=1;
        }

        if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
        {
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
        }
        else if($extension=="png")
        {
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
        }
        else 
        {
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
        }

        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

        $newwidth=600;
        /*$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;*/
        $newheight=600;
        $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

        $encodeimage =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));//here we got encodede image value

        $encrypt_image = "data:".$filetype.";base64,".$encodeimage;



        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        }
        }

        function getExtension($str) {

                 $i = strrpos($str,".");
                 if (!$i) { return ""; } 

                 $l = strlen($str) - $i;
                 $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
                 return $ext;
         }

        $id_proof = array(/*"filename" =>$filename,*/
                          "base64_encodedimage" =>$encrypt_image,
                          "encryptedData" => $encrypted,
                          /*"error_msg" =>$error_msg,*/
                            );
        echo json_encode($id_proof)
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you know what encryption is. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i want do id proof upload so can do secure,so i am doing like this

Comment: What do you mean by "id proof upload"?

Comment: The words "secure" and "base64" probably shouldn't ever be in the same sentence, this one being an exception.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the content after encoding use bellow code to covert and display

```
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
    file_put_contents("abc.jpg", $unencodedData);
```

Comment: Don't want display,i want to encrypt for base64 value

Comment: that value already in encryption format if you again want to encrypt it then use md5 n etc...